# Space between table and caption in Beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, spacing, captions

I am making a slide using Stockton beamer theme.

I have added a table to a frame, however as you can see in the screenshot, that space between caption and table is too much. I made some search and found these codes,

```
\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[table]{belowskip=1pt,aboveskip=1pt}

\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
```

[image]

However, they both are not working. How can I solve this problem? Table looks so bad in this slide.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Stockton}

\usepackage{epsfig} %for figures
\usepackage{xcolor} %for color

\definecolor{hughesblue}{rgb}{.9,.9,1} %A blue I like to use for highlighting, matches Hughes Hallet's book

\logo{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{Seal_Cream.pdf}} % comment out this line if you do not have the pacific-seal file}

\title[Short Title \hspace{4em}\insertframenumber/
\inserttotalframenumber]{~ \\ Long Title:  A Sample Using \\ Stockton Beamer Theme \\~} 

\author[short author name or speaker]{ \\ Sarah Merz, The University of the Pacific } 

\date{January, 2010}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{INPUT SELECTION}
\begin{itemize}
\item The load is influenced by many factors.:
\end{itemize}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption {Factors that may influence electricity demand}
\label{table:1}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{15cm}|}\hline
  Calendar data & hour of the day, day of the week, holidays, 'bridge days', daylight saving time, school holidays\\\hline
  Meteorological data & temperature, humidity, cloud cover, luminosity, earth's position in the eclipse, sun's altitude, wind speed, solar radiation, climate change\\\hline
  Economic data & GDP, per capita GDP, consumer price index, average salary earnings, production plans of companies, electricity price, industrial expansion\\\hline
  Demographic data & number of households, population growth, local area development\\\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
\begin{itemize}
\item The importance of horizon:
\begin{itemize}
\item For very short-term forecast (up to 6 hours) $\longrightarrow$ inputs based on past load values
\end{itemize}
\item Engineering judgment or human experience as well as some statistical/graphical analysis
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It appears to be a problem of stockton, I commented the line out and the result had a smaller gap between caption and table.

Comment: In beamer presentations you don't need floats. Hence, you don't need to put your tabular inside a table environment because it's not a float. You don't even need to caption them because it's not a float. Subfig is not related to caption but caption offers a `\captionof` command for captioning objects that are not a float. And lastly you just have too much text on a slide.

Comment: I take your code (without captionsetup) and get  http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1897885/space_table_caption.pdf. I think there aren't extra spaces between caption and table here.

Comment: Using `caption` package and setting `skip=0pt` seem to do the work. It only looks like there is a big space between the caption and the table because the table text is smaller compared to the default font size. And, afaik, specifying `!htbp` does not work in `beamer`. And as **percusse** has mentioned, instead of the `table` environment, you might want to use the `\captionof` command instead.

Comment: Since `figure` and `table` are no floating environments in `beamer` I don't see the point why not using them.

Comment: The `figure` and `table` environments seem like to add padding and hence the extra white spaces.

Comment: BTW: I don't understand why using `\captionof` is still popular. Why should I use a command of the pre-pdf-era which tend to give me bad hyperlinks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`belowskip=0pt` of `caption` package seems to do the job. Also, the `table` environment is adding whitespace between text and the `table`. You can use `\captionof` command instead.

## Code

```
\documentclass[xcolor=svgnames]{beamer} 
\usetheme{Stockton}

\usepackage{epsfig} %for figures
\usepackage{xcolor} %for color

\definecolor{hughesblue}{rgb}{.9,.9,1} %A blue I like to use for highlighting, matches Hughes Hallet's book

%\logo{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{Seal_Cream.pdf}} % comment out this line if you do not have the pacific-seal file}

\title[Short Title \hspace{4em}\insertframenumber/
\inserttotalframenumber]{~ \\ Long Title:  A Sample Using \\ Stockton Beamer Theme \\~} 

\author[short author name or speaker]{Sarah Merz, The University of the Pacific } 

\date{January, 2010}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{INPUT SELECTION}
\begin{itemize}
\item The load is influenced by many factors.:
\end{itemize}
%\begin{table}[!htbp]
\captionof{table}{Factors that may influence electricity demand\label{table:1}}
%\captionof{table}{Factors that may influence electricity demand}
%\label{table:1}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{15cm}|}\hline
  Calendar data & hour of the day, day of the week, holidays, 'bridge days', daylight saving time, school holidays\\\hline
  Meteorological data & temperature, humidity, cloud cover, luminosity, earth's position in the eclipse, sun's altitude, wind speed, solar radiation, climate change\\\hline
  Economic data & GDP, per capita GDP, consumer price index, average salary earnings, production plans of companies, electricity price, industrial expansion\\\hline
  Demographic data & number of households, population growth, local area development\\\hline
\end{tabular}}
%\end{table}
\begin{itemize}
\item The importance of horizon:
\begin{itemize}
\item For very short-term forecast (up to 6 hours) $\longrightarrow$ inputs based on past load values
\end{itemize}
\item Engineering judgment or human experience as well as some statistical/graphical analysis
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Much obliged, it works great!